# SSL certificate valid in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have installed an ssl certificate with letsencrypt (actually, my provider has an automated workflow for this which I used).

As the title says: in Chrome (Chromium in Linux) it says that it is safe. In Firefox (also on Linux) it says that the connection is not secure.

I tried googling why that is but that didn't yield any results (or I am really bad at googling)

So my question is: Why?

Comment: Did you install the whole LetsEncrypt chain, or just your end-entity certificate?  Chrome (and Edge) look for missing CA certificates in the chain using the AIA extension, while Firefox doesn't use this facility.

Comment: Run `echo "" | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <your fqdn here>:443` and see if the server sends all the certs, or just one.

Comment: Check your site with  [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and you'll like see "chain issues" or similar. Fix this by sending all the chain certificates in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I'll look into each hint.